# "Internal error: Unexpected failure when preparing tensor allocations" - Firebase MLKIT - Android - Local Model load failed

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I am using Firebase MLKIT to implement the ".tflite" model locally in-app. The model.tflite file is around 132 MB in size. 
It shows the error cause:

**onFailure: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal error: Unexpected failure when preparing tensor allocations: Regular TensorFlow ops are not supported by this interpreter. Make sure you invoke the Flex delegate before inference.Node number 17 (Flex) failed to prepare.**

and error message:

**Local model load failed with the model options: Local model path: model.tflite. Remote model name: unspecified.**

The model is being used to convert one normal image into a black and white image [with some purpose].

I am listing the dependencies as well,

- implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-model-interpreter:22.0.3'
- implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:1.13.1'

I also visited the link but am unable to understand how to handle this problem in my case: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/java/src/test/java/org/tensorflow/lite/InterpreterFlexTest.java

I am attaching the code snippet too:

'''

```
FirebaseCustomLocalModel localModel = null;
                try {
                    localModel = new FirebaseCustomLocalModel.Builder()
                            .setAssetFilePath("model.tflite")
                            .build();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: "+e);
                }
                FirebaseModelInterpreter interpreter;
                FirebaseModelInterpreterOptions options =
                        new FirebaseModelInterpreterOptions.Builder(localModel).build();
                try {

                    interpreter = FirebaseModelInterpreter.getInstance(options);

                    FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions inputOutputOptions =
                            new FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions.Builder()
                                    .setInputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.FLOAT32, new int[]{1, 256, 256, 3})
                                    .setOutputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.FLOAT32, new int[]{420, 580})
                                    .build();
                    Bitmap bitmap = getYourInputImage();
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 256, 256, true);

                    int batchNum = 0;
                    float[][][][] input = new float[1][256][256][3];
                    for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
                        for (int y = 0; y < 256; y++) {
                            int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
                            // Normalize channel values to [-1.0, 1.0]. This requirement varies by
                            // model. For example, some models might require values to be normalized
                            // to the range [0.0, 1.0] instead.
                            input[batchNum][x][y][0] = (Color.red(pixel) - 127) / 128.0f;
                            input[batchNum][x][y][1] = (Color.green(pixel) - 127) / 128.0f;
                            input[batchNum][x][y][2] = (Color.blue(pixel) - 127) / 128.0f;
                        }
                    }
                    FirebaseModelInputs inputs = new FirebaseModelInputs.Builder()
                            .add(input)  // add() as many input arrays as your model requires
                            .build();
                   // Log.d(TAG, "onClick: "+inputs.toString()+"\n"+inputOutputOptions.toString());
                    interpreter.run(inputs, inputOutputOptions)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(
                                    new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseModelOutputs>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(FirebaseModelOutputs result) {
                                            // ...
                                            float[][] output = result.getOutput(0);
                                            float[] probabilities = output[0];
                                            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: "+result.getOutput(0).toString());
                                        }
                                    })
                            .addOnFailureListener(
                                    new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            // Task failed with an exception
                                            // ...
                                            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: "+e.getCause()+"\n\n"+e.getLocalizedMessage()+"\n\n"+e.getMessage());
                                        }
                                    });

                } catch (FirebaseMLException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: "+e);
                    // ...
                }
```

'''

Let me know what needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Flex ops are not supported with FirebaseModelInterpreter. You should use the tflite Interpreter (org.tensorflow.Interpreter) directly instead.

Use the FirebaseModelManager to download the tflite file:

```
    Task<File> fileTask = FirebaseModelManager.getInstance()
              .getLatestModelFile(remoteModel);
    File modelFile = fileTask.getResult();
```

Add the aar dependencies for flex to your build.gradle along with the Firebase dependencies:
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select#android_aar

From that point you can follow the general path of the gist in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/java/src/test/java/org/tensorflow/lite/InterpreterFlexTest.java

```
    FlexDelegate delegate = new FlexDelegate();
    Interpreter.Options options = new Interpreter.Options().addDelegate(delegate);
    Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter(fileBuffer, options);
    interpreter.run(inputs, outputs)
```

Hope that helps